# Accepting localized Date input on Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, localization

Have a form for submitting date in russian, typical input will be like:

"1 апреля 2020"

Also have a serializer:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    delivery_date = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d %B %Y',])
```

At `settings.py` have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

When i send `delivery_date` to rest API it returns an error:

```
{"delivery_date":["Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: DD [January-December] YYYY."]}
```

**Is it possible in DRF to accept non-english Date value?**

Upd (on *@GlennDJ* comment):

my `view.py`

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response    
from .serializers import CartSerializer

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def add_tocart_api(request):
    ...
    serializer = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
    print(serializer)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Didn't use django forms here just sent `{delivery_date: "22 Октября 2021"}` from frontend via ajax (js fetch)

Comment: Can you show the code where you link `CartSerializer` to the view/form?

Comment: @GlennDJ updated the question on your comment, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using a 3rd party library, you can subclass `rest_framework.serializers.DateTimeField` and replace its `.datetime_parser` property with one that uses [arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) for conversion:

Implementation:

```py
import arrow
from rest_framework import serializers


class ArrowDateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):

    def __init__(self, format=empty, input_formats=None, default_timezone=None, **kwargs):
        locale = kwargs.pop('locale', None)
        super().__init__(format, input_formats, default_timezone, **kwargs)
        if locale:
            self.datetime_parser = lambda dtstr, fmt: arrow.get(dtstr, fmt, locale=locale)
```

Usage:

```py
from { whichever module you put it } import ArrowDateTimeField  


adtf = ArrowDateTimeField(input_formats=['D MMMM YYYY'], locale='ru-ru')

print(adtf.to_internal_value("1 апреля 2020"))
# .to_internal_value method will reach for .datetime_parser internally
```

please notice you must provide [Arrow's own tokens](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#supported-tokens) to `input_format`, they are different from Python standards.